# MathML rendering issue on mobile browser

Tags: html, deployment, mathml

I have a slight issue while rendering math equations using MathML on mobile: Where the parenthesis of a matrix appears like this:

[image]

It renders perfectly on desktop, but not on mobile ? Is there any way to fix this ?
Here is the code for the above image:

```
<math display="block" class="tml-display" style="display:block math;">
  <mrow>
    <mo fence="true" form="prefix">[</mo>
    <mtable columnalign="center center">
      <mtr>
        <mtd style="padding-left:0em;">
          <mn>1</mn>
        </mtd>
        <mtd style="padding-right:0em;">
          <mn>1</mn>
        </mtd>
      </mtr>
      <mtr>
        <mtd style="padding-left:0em;">
          <mn>1</mn>
        </mtd>
        <mtd style="padding-right:0em;">
          <mn>1</mn>
        </mtd>
      </mtr>
    </mtable>
    <mo fence="true" form="postfix">]</mo>
  </mrow>
</math>
```

Comment: Mobile, as in iOS and Safari or Android and Chrome? Or another browser? Since this feature is [browser/platform dependent](https://caniuse.com/mathml).

Comment: Chrome browser on an android mobile. I didn't mention it since, I thought this was a  general issue on all mobiles.

Comment: I tested your code on Android in Chrome, and indeed, it doesn't work. It does however work in Firefox, if that's useful to you. You could have a careful look at [this conversation](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/n4zf_3FWmAA/m/oait3tsMAQAJ?pli=1), but you need to be willing to dive a bit deeper into this.